# Ansible playbook script requires "press enter to continue"

Tags: ansible

I like to create an Ansible playbook which utilize a script (`pre-requirements.sh`) that requires "press enter to continue".

```json
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_expect_payload_x4zBUF/ansible_expect_payload.zip/ansible/modules/commands/expect.py", line 108, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pexpect
fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "chdir": null,
            "command": "pre-requirements.sh",
            "creates": null,
            "echo": false,
            "removes": null,
            "responses": {
                "PRESS \\<ENTER\\> TO CONTINUE:": ""
            },
            "timeout": 30
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (pexpect) on server1's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"
}
```

Expected output is for the playbook to wait for enter to be pressed on users keyboard.

Above error is displayed.

Is there any other module or method to use for user input when running ansible playbook?

I've have done `yum install pextect` but the version is not compatible with our Ansible.

```json
TASK [Running pre-req script] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "msg": "Insufficient version of pexpect installed (2.3), this module requires pexpect>=3.3. Error was 'module' object has no attribute 'runu'"}
```

Comment: Hi. Please read [ask] and pay attention to the paragraph about [mre]. As is, the error you display seems to have nothing to do with the feature you describe and it's impossible to guess what your playbook looks like. Meanwhile, the error by itself is very explicitly telling you to `pip install pexpect` on your target server.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ansible module `expect`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html) requires the [Python package `pexpect`](https://pypi.org/project/pexpect/).

1. check that python3-pip is installed
   (`yum install python3-pip`)

   ```yaml
   - name: install python's pip
     yum:
       name: python3-pip
   ```
2. install the Python package `pexpect`

   ```yaml
   - name: install pexpect via pip
     pip:
       name: pexpect
   ```
3. use the Ansible module `expect`

   ```yaml
   - name: run shell script and answer it's questions
     expect:
       command: "/path/to/your/script.sh"
       responses:
       "scripts question:": "your answer"
   ```